# Refresh image in label after every 1s using simple function

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to refresh the Label Image after every 1s I have created one class in which only one time I 'll click on the button to display the image and after that, it will refresh after every second but unable to make that work

Earlier I was trying to make it work with canvas but it wasn't helping me out by showing it through label but was able to refresh using

```
self.canvas.after(100, self.loopCap)
```

but now in a label widget, I am not able to understand how refreshing the label every time

Code for is mentioned below:

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(StartPage)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        """Destroys current frame and replaces it with a new one."""
        new_frame = frame_class(self)
        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()
        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class StartPage(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, bg='powder blue')
        self.master.geometry('700x500+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg='powder blue')

        self.username = tk.StringVar()
        self.password = tk.StringVar()
        tk.Label(self, text='Sealant Login System', font=('arial', 30, 'bold'), bg='powder blue',
                              fg='black').pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10,anchor='n')

        # =====================================================================================================

        tk.Label(self, text="UserID: ", bg='powder blue').pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Entry(self, font=('arial', 15, 'bold'), textvariable=self.username).pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=5, expand=1)
        tk.Label(self, text="Password: ", bg='powder blue').pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Entry(self, font=('arial', 15, 'bold'), textvariable=self.password).pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=5)
        tk.Button(self, text="Login",bg='cadet blue',
                  command=self.Login_System).pack(side="top",fill="y")
        tk.Button(self, text="Reset",bg='cadet blue',
                  command=self.Rest).pack(side="bottom",fill="y")
    def Login_System(self):
        u = (self.username.get())
        p = (self.password.get())

        if (u == str("admin") and p == str("admin")):
            self.master.switch_frame(PageOne)

    def Rest(self):
        self.username.set("")
        self.password.set("")
        self.master.focus()


class PageOne(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, bg='powder blue')
        tk.Label(self, text='Sealant Reference System', font=('arial', 30, 'bold'), bg='powder blue',
                 fg='black').pack(side="top", fill="x", pady=10, anchor='n')
        tk.Label(self, text="Accuracy: ", bg='powder blue').pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10, anchor='n')
        tk.Label(self, text="Variable", bg='powder blue').pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10, anchor='n')
        tk.Label(self, text="No of Jobs: ", bg='powder blue').pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10, anchor='n')
        tk.Label(self, text="Variable", bg='powder blue').pack(side="left", fill="x", pady=10, anchor='n')
        tk.Button(self, text="Return to start page",
                  command= lambda: master.switch_frame(PageTwo)).pack(side="bottom")

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):
    def loopCap(self):
        # self.label = Label(self.master, image=self.img, textvariable=self.text)
        self.img = Image.open("img.jpg")
        self.label = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)
        tk.Label(self, image=self.label).pack()
        print("updated")
        self.master.after(1000, self.loopCap)

    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master,bg='powder blue')
        self.master.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg='powder blue')
        tk.Button(self, text="Return to start page",
                  command=self.loopCap).pack()
        # self.canvas.scale(master, from_=0, to=42, tickinterval=8)
        print("Load")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

Suggestions will be much appreciated

Comment: inside function `loopCap` you have to run `after(100, self.loopCap)` to execute this function again after 100ms. And this function will run again `after()`, etc. so it will update all time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `loopCap` you have to run `after()`

```
def loopCap(self):
    # ... code ...
    self.master.after(1000, self.loopCap) # 1000ms = 1s
```

and it will repeate function again and again.

You can use this method to change `Label` or `Canvas`. There is no difference.

---

If you want to stop and start it again using two buttons then you can use variable `True/False` - ie. `self.repeate` - to stop `after()`

```
def __init__(self, master):
    self.repeate = False
    tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.on_start)
    tk.Button(self, text="Stop",  command=self.on_stop)

def loopCap(self):
    # ... code ...
    if self.repeate:
        self.after(1000, self.loopCap)

def on_start(self):
    if self.repeated:
        print('already running')
    else:
        print('starting')
        self.repeated = True
        self.loopCap()

def on_stop(self):
    if self.repeated:
        print('stoping')
        self.repeated = False
    else:
        print('not running')
```

---

**EDIT:** You have to create label at start and later change only images in label. And you need two or more images for this.

```
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class SampleApp(tk.Tk):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self._frame = None
        self.switch_frame(PageTwo)

    def switch_frame(self, frame_class):
        new_frame = frame_class(self)

        if self._frame is not None:
            self._frame.destroy()

        self._frame = new_frame
        self._frame.pack()

class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def loopCap(self):

        self.current_photo += 1
        if self.current_photo >= len(self.photo):
            self.current_photo = 0

        self.label['image'] = self.photo[self.current_photo]

        print("updated")

        self.master.after(1000, self.loopCap)


    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, bg='powder blue')

        self.master.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg='powder blue')

        b = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.loopCap)
        b.pack()

        self.img = [
            Image.open("image1.jpg"),
            Image.open("image2.jpg"),
            Image.open("image3.jpg"),
        ]

        self.photo = [
            ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img[0]),
            ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img[1]),
            ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img[2]),
        ]

        self.current_photo = 1

        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label.pack()

        print("Load")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = SampleApp()
    app.mainloop()
```

---

**EDIT:** for single image always loaded from file

```
class PageTwo(tk.Frame):

    def loopCap(self):

        self.img = Image.open("image.jpg")
        self.photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.img)

        self.label['image'] = self.photo

        print("updated")

        self.master.after(1000, self.loopCap)


    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master, bg='powder blue')

        self.master.geometry('1350x750+0+0')
        self.master.config(bg='powder blue')

        b = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.loopCap)
        b.pack()

        self.label = tk.Label(self)
        self.label.pack()

        print("Load")
```

Comment: I did that way but its updating blank screen instead of a refreshing image, I have edited and updated my full code, not able to understand problem, also dont want to stop and restart just whenever I click the button it will display and refresh every time

Comment: I see one problem - you create new Label for new image. You should create one Label at start and change image in Label - `label['image'] = new_image`

Comment: other problem - you have only one image so you will no see it is changed.

Comment: Actually, I am trying to overwrite the same image again and again that is why I want to refresh the label. The 2nd last method recommended by you will be the best option for me, can you please update your code, I am not able to make that thing work

Comment: should I intialise `self.current_photo=0` in class, I am facing some kind of error `self.label['image'] = self.photo[self.current_photo]
AttributeError: 'PageTwo' object has no attribute 'current_photo'`

Comment: sorry, it should be `self.photo` without `[self.current_photo]`